# Idiomatic way to content based routing with RxJava

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

Does anyone hows of an idiomatic way to do [content based routing](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/ContentBasedRouter.html) in RxJava or Reactive Stream ?

I can see how one can create a reactive message processing pipeline using standard operator like map filter and transform.

But I can't see one idiomatic why using operators to switch between several possible pipelines.
I would like to be able to trigger one off many processing pipelines based on one initial input object or map, so that depending on the contents of the input map or object a diferent pipeline is chosen.

The idea is I need to make one several possible requests to an external api and what determines the api and the pipeline to be triggered in depended on the input object to my controller.

I know this can be done with Spring integration or Camel, but my use case does not need the full flexibility of an integration engine as munch deen able to deal with latency on the wire.

Thank you, kindly

Comment: Do you mean 'idiomatic way'?

Comment: I am sorry by idiomatic way, I mean using one built in operator. Tx

Comment: Yeah I thought you meant idiomatic way which is fine the text says 'idiomatic why'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Content based routing is a job for `flatMap`:

```
observable.flatMap(x -> {
    if (isA(x))
        return observableA(x);
    else 
        return observableB(x);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use operator GroupBy which allow you to emmitt different groups of items http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/groupby.html

You can see some examples of groupBy here. https://github.com/politrons/reactive/blob/master/src/test/java/rx/observables/transforming/ObservableGroupBy.java